# Comparing the results of a YAML file to the output of a SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, yaml

I’m currently trying to run some python logic which has done the following:

Ran a SQL query against an Oracle DB and returned the results of said query, the result being as follows (a list)

```
[('DATA1', 39305), ('DATA2', 35892), ('DATA3', 3711), ('DATA4', 0)]
```

Grab the contents of a YAML file from a Gitlab repository, which looks like this (a string):

```
expected:
  table: DATA1
  counts:
    “Count1”: 109
    “Count2”: 39305
    “Count3”: 39414

  table: DATA2
  counts:
    “Count1”: 109
    “Count2”: 35738
    “Count3”: 35892

  table: DATA3
  counts:
    “Count1”: 85
    “Count2”: 3626
    “Count3: 3711
```

I'd’ve like to compare the results of the SQL query to the YAML file where the data is the same (e.g. Count2 of DATA1 from the YAML file is the same as the results derived from DATA1 of the SQL Query) and then return some output to say that the data correlates or whatever.

I’m thinking that in order to make them work together, I’d first have to convert both into the same format (dictionary maybe?) but beyond that I’m struggling.

Comment: That what you pasted is **not** a valid YAML document because there are duplicate keys in the mapping that is the value for key `expected`. YAML parsers should throw an error (if they are compliant) but some non-conforming parsers silently overwrite duplicate keys with values occuring later in the mapping. Please provide a link to the original file in gitlab, or at least update your contents to valid YAML document (e.g. there might be missing dash + space before each `table:`